# Spring boot don't detect css and images

Tags: html, css, image, spring-boot

I need help. I use spring boot, but my index page does not detect css file and images. Тhis way i insert a link to the css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
```

and this for images

```
<img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" width=90% height=80%>
```

[image]

I try to delete browser cache data and run project again, but the css and images don't show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `static` folder inside `resources`. 
Put `css` and `images` folders in `static` folder.
Restart spring